# Laravel notifications not working (composer error)

Tags: php, laravel, notifications

I made a simple notification controller using:
`php artisan make:notification DocNotification`
I made no modifications to it.

Then I have this HomeController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
 

use App\Notifications\DocNotification;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;

 



    public function index()

    {

        Notification::route('mail', 'email@test.com')->notify(new DocNotification());

    }

}
```

And I am getting this error:
[image: Error]

Comment: you don't have a high enough version of PHP to use Laravel 8

Comment: I am using 7.4.5

Comment: your class name is missing can u check

Comment: @grimdbx that isn't the version that is being used otherwise you would not be getting that error

Comment: @Kamlesh Paul I don't understand where is missing. Can you be more specific please?

Comment: @lagbox If I write php -v in console 7.4.5 is what I'm getting.

Comment: `class HomeController { ` this is missing

Comment: that doesn't mean that is the one that is being used by your webserver .... again the version of PHP you are using does not support trailing commas in parameter lists for calling functions ... so therefor you are not using the correct version of PHP ... sorry you don't understand

Comment: You can check the version by creating a file in the public folder with just `<? phpinfo();` and going to that file in the browser

Comment: @Kamlesh Paul I trimmed the code, but it's there

Comment: @grimdbx can u check your `homeController line no 27` and put in questions as in error stack it is showing

Comment: Hi, please can you [edit] your question to include the full error as text, rather than image. That way, it can be viewed by people with small screens or visual impairments, and importantly will show up in search results for other people facing the same issue in future. Please also ensure that the code you post is relevant to the error - what you've posted is not valid PHP, and clearly not 51 lines long, so is impossible to relate to the error message mentioning a syntax error on line 51.

Comment: @IMSoP because the error is coming from a library not their code ... they are only posting a truncated version of their code because it is what causes the library code to be called ... they are using the wrong version of PHP

Comment: @lagbox It doesn't really matter _who_ wrote the code; a syntax error is in a particular file, and the code you need to show is that file, unless you're doing something _really_ funky with dynamic code generation. (I've upvoted your answer, by the way, but I've also voted to close the question for not providing the debugging information in a readable and searchable format.)

Comment: @IMSoP yes pictures of text are a plague on this site

Comment: @lagbox Then please join me in not rewarding users for posting them, and clicking "close" rather than "answer" when you see them. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong version of PHP. The version of PHP that you are using does not support the feature of trailing commas in parameter lists when making calls. This is a feature that was added in 7.3.

The error proves this.

For Laravel 8 you need PHP >= 7.3.

[PHP.net manual - 7.3 New Features - Trailing Commas](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration73.new-features.php#migration73.new-features.core.trailing-commas)

Answer (score -1):

You are missing controller class add your controller class name

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Notifications\DocNotification;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;
YourClass_name extends extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
 Notification::route('mail', 'email@test.com')->notify(new DocNotification());
}
}
```

Comment: I trimmed the code because stackoverflow didn't let me post with so much code and little text. But the class name is present